# Update notifications from broadcast Receiver in android

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have a broadcast receiver, which starts an intent service.

Intent service triggers notification.

If there are multiple notifications fired, then since the NOTIFICATION_ID is same it doesn't update.

Is there any way to know how many notifications have been fired ?
So that I can update my notification accordingly.

I don't want to fire separate notification. I want to update the existing notification. All I need here to figure out is the number  of notifications already fired while firing a notification. And that number should reset when user click on it.

Comment: Create any triggerNotification() method in service and call it every time notification is fired, in that method take one variable 'int num=0' and increment it every your method is called. then again use builder.setContentText(String.valueOf(num)); and 
notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build()); to update the notification

Comment: And declare that variable static ? I have tried that. But the behavior is unpredictable.
Sometimes it updates the variable and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: what do you need the number of notifications for?  i think you are doing something fundamentally wrong...

Comment: If the user receive one message, I want to display the display the message he has received. If he has received > 1 then I want to display that he has received n messages.

Comment: then you know how many messages were received,  so what's the problem actually?

Comment: No ! I don't know how many messages are received. That is what I want to know.

Comment: so when are you calling NotificationManager.notify?

Comment: Every time the user receives a message.

Answer (score 0):

In your notify method make below changes.

notificationManager.notify(getID(), notification);

The getId() method will provide unique id so that multiple notification will come at same time.

private final static AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(3);

```
public static int getID() {
    return c.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to fire separate notification. I want to update the existing notification. All I need here to figure out is the number  of notifications already fired while firing a notification. And that number should reset when user click on it.

Comment: You can use shared preference for storing that integer value.Every time when notification fires increment that value and again store in shared preference.

When you click on notification and redirect to any activity,service or broadcast receiver there set your preference variable to 0

Comment: I thought of it as a last resort. Is there no in-built way to update notifications in Android ? :O